# Qt: Select folders and files using QFileDialog, using the native dialog

Tags: qt, qfiledialog

Is there any chance to be able to select both files and folders using the same dialog, using `QFileDialog` and without setting the option: `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` ?

I've tried the solutions posted previously to allow selectiong both types, but they all require to set `DontUseNativeDialog`, and I'd like to take advantage of the native dialog look & feel, the software works on multiple platforms and it makes it easier...

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, only the static functions support native file dialogs on Windows. With instancing `QFileDialog`, this seems to be impossible. (But I really would enjoy to read somehing else here.) :-)

Comment: I just had a look into woboq [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp.html#_ZN11QFileDialog15getOpenFileNameEP7QWidgetRK7QStringS4_S4_PS2_6QFlagsINS_6OptionEE) to see the difference and was surprised that this calls [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileUrl()`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qfiledialog.cpp.html#_ZN11QFileDialog14getOpenFileUrlEP7QWidgetRK7QStringRK4QUrlS4_PS2_6QFlagsINS_6OptionEERK11QStringList) which in turn just constructs a local instance of `QFileDialog`.

Comment: ... So, it shouldn't make a difference but then I found the following remark in the doc. of [`QFileDialog::getOpenFileName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName): _On Windows, and macOS, this static function will use the native file dialog and not a QFileDialog._ The doc. of constructors doesn't mention anything about this. This makes me somehow feel that my first statement is really the (sad) truth.

Comment: too bad... :( I forwarded the question to Qt Team, will post their response, so we are all aware... thanks @Scheff